# R drawing baseline in facet_wrap specific to each facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
set.seed(42)

data <- data.frame(type = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 40, replace = T),
                   condition = sample(c("Control", "Treatment"), 40, replace = T),
                   measurement = runif(40))
```

And I'd like to create the facetted graph:

```
ggplot(data, aes( x= condition, y = measurement))+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

I'd like also to show the baseline (with geom_hline, for example), that equals mean of control values (mean(data$measurement[data$condition == "Control"]). But because control values will be different in different types (meaning facets on the graph), I can't just calculate one single mean. As they will be different between the facets.

Is there any way to specify yintercept for geom_hline between different facets ?

Something like this, but with the specified yintercept value, calculating the mean values for the control group for each individual facet:

```
ggplot(data, aes( x= condition, y = measurement))+
 geom_point()+
 geom_hline(yintercept= mean(data$measurement[data$condition == "Control"]),
            linetype="dashed", 
            color = "red", size=1)+
 facet_wrap(~type)
```

Thanks a lot!
Best regards,
Eugene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stat_summary` with `fun = mean` and `geom = "hline"`, passing only the control subset to the `data` parameter. You can map `yintercept` to the `y` value calculated by the stat.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = condition, y = measurement))+
  geom_point() +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "hline", aes(yintercept = after_stat(y)),
               data = data[data$condition == "Control",], color = "red",
               linetype = "dashed") +
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

[image]

Comment: I almost newer use stat_summary or other stat_... Do you think is it important to learn more about these things. Many thanks!

Comment: @TarJae honestly, I don't think they are massively useful, and it's difficult to think of a situation where you _need_ them. They are really just wrangling the data for you to achieve common transformations, so they are mostly just a way of having to avoid  doing that yourself and passing a mutated copy of your data to another layer. They can make your code a bit more succinct and easy to read, but often at the cost of flexibility. If you were thinking "why not just group, summarize and filter the data and pass that to `geom_hline`?" then I really think that's an equally valid approach.

Comment: TarJae, Yes, at least for me, stat_ functions are very convenient as you can pre-process the data while graphing.

Comment: Allan, could I ask you to explain basics for me here ? Why does in your example stat_summary() function work individually for every facet (processes and passes the data specific to each individual facet), but in my example geom_hline() just uses all the dataset once and makes one value for all the facets ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eugene you are passing a single number to the yintercept (the mean value of your control column), so it can only produce a single value for hline. What stat_ and geom_ functions do is take the whole data set, split the data according to which facet they are in (and any grouping aesthetic such as color and fill),  apply any requested transformations, then pass this transformed data to the required aesthetic (in this case yintercept). What I am doing with stat_summary is saying: "for each facet, calculate the mean and map this to yintercept."

Comment: Thank you, Allan. What I mean is that I point the code to the following dataset: `yintercept= mean(data$measurement[data$condition == "Control"])` and you use very similar `data = data[data$condition == "Control",]` . But in my case the soft indeed reads it as a single value, but in your case the soft uses the data specific to the facet (splitted by type value). Probably, that's due to `after_stat()` function ...

Comment: @Eugene no, yintercept is the aesthetic value you need to map the data to. If you pass it a single value, it will only give you a single value. Passing the subsetted data frame to `data` is completely different. It allows the stat to _calculate_ the yintercept, and it does it for each facet. A single value to yintercept doesn't pay any attention to groups or facets.

Comment: So, does it mean that I can put `data` argument in `geom_hline` and then it will use it specifically for each facet ?